# Unable to call SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides from Context.executeQueryAsync in JS Link

Tags: jslink

exceute SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides from Context.executeQueryAsync  Success

Below is my code

```
(function () { 
    var isCurrentUserInGroup;
    var flag=false;
    var hiddenFiledContext = {}; 
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup, 'sp.js');    
    function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup() {           
        var currentContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);
        allGroups = currentUser.get_groups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);
        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);
    }

    function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
         isCurrentUserInGroup = false;          
         var groupsEnum = allGroups.getEnumerator();
         while (groupsEnum.moveNext()) {
             var item = groupsEnum.get_current();
             groupName = item.get_title();
             if (groupName.includes("Site Members")) {
                 isCurrentUserInGroup = true;               
                 break;
             }
         }
         SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CSR_Setup, 'sp.js');

    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
       isCurrentUserInGroup=false;

    } 

    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/sites/dev-akansha/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>'));  

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    function CSR_Setup(){

        hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {};  
        hiddenFiledContext.Templates.OnPostRender = hiddenFiledOnPreRender; 
        alert(isCurrentUserInGroup);
        if(isCurrentUserInGroup){
            hiddenFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
                // Apply the new rendering for Age field on New and Edit forms 
                "Test1": { 

                    "EditForm": hiddenFiledTemplate 
                } 

            }; 
        }
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(hiddenFiledContext);
    }

})(); 


// This function provides the rendering logic 
function hiddenFiledTemplate() { 
    return "<span class='csrHiddenField'></span>"; 
} 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function hiddenFiledOnPreRender(ctx) { 
    jQuery(".csrHiddenField").closest("tr").hide(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things you have to understand is that page rendering happens very early in the life of the page, and by the time `sp.js` is loaded, the rendering cycle is over and done with.  So you really can't wait until `sp.js` is loaded before calling your `CSR_Setup` function.

When I want to hide fields based on group membership, I take kind of an opposite approach, because waiting for an async call to execute and *then* determining if I should hide the field or not would possibly result in the field being visible for a brief moment and then disappearing.  So I usually try to hide the field as soon as possible (for everyone), then make the async call to check group membership, and then if the user *is* a member of the correct group, *show* the already hidden field.

Restructuring your code to achieve that would look something like this:

```
// ensure jquery is loaded
(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/sites/dev-akansha/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>'));

// register your override and set up your field to be hidden 
(function () {
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {};
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        // Apply the new rendering for Age field on New and Edit forms 
        "Test1": {
            "EditForm": hiddenFiledTemplate
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(hiddenFiledContext);
})();

function hiddenFiledTemplate() {
    return "<span class='csrHiddenField'></span>";
}

// after the rendering runs, your span is there and ready to be found.
// _spBodyOnLoad functions run after the DOM is loaded, so the page
// will have been rendered by the time the next function is called
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('HideMyField');

function HideMyField() {
    jQuery(".csrHiddenField").closest("tr").hide();
    // then set up the async call
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup, 'sp.js');
}

// declare this outside the scope of the async call function 
// so it is available in the success callback
var allGroups;

function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup() {
    var currentContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
    var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    currentContext.load(currentUser);
    allGroups = currentUser.get_groups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);
}

function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
    var groupsEnum = allGroups.getEnumerator();
    while (groupsEnum.moveNext()) {
        var item = groupsEnum.get_current();
        groupName = item.get_title();
        if (groupName.includes("Site Members")) {
            ShowMyField();
            break;
        }
    }
}

function OnFailure(sender, args) {
    // log an error?
    // no need to do anything with the field because it is already hidden
}

function ShowMyField() {
    jQuery(".csrHiddenField").closest("tr").show();
}
```

The part of that I am unsure about is the dynamic loading of jQuery.  I do not usually use that technique so I am not sure if the syntax is correct for that line of code.  But in a more general sense, that is how I would go about structuring my code to hide a field based on group membership when using an async call to check the membership.

Comment: Hi Dylan. I want to make the fields readonly on the basis of the logged in user.